# IOS/IPod framework, how to retrieve Song with only MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

Is there any 'easier' way of retrieving a song from the Music Library (given you have the **MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID**)

This is what i'm using at the moment:

I have a NSArray (trackList) stored with **MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID** ids. Now i want to load each media item. But this seems all a bit cumbersome to load a song (i.e. MPMediaItem).

Then inside my *cellForRowAtIndexPath* (UITableView) i retrieve each MPMediaItem like this:

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:               [trackList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
MPMediaQuery *mediaQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[mediaQuery addFilterPredicate: predicate];
MPMediaItem *item = [[mediaQuery items] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Any more *elegant* solution?

Comment: I guess you are trying to handle the case where the song is no longer on the device, right? Why not delay worrying about until did you call didSelectRowAtIndexPath? Oh, also check it when you go to USE the persistentID. But this way you'll call MPMediaQuery far fewer times.

Comment: Not specifically, its really more about a quick way of retrieving the meta data. Although you have a good point.